# Error in using class's public function when passed my reference c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to create a sorting function for vector.
This is what I have written

```
struct Xgreater
    {
        bool operator()( const lineCommand& lx, const lineCommand& rx ) const {
            return lx.getEndTime() < rx.getEndTime();
        }
    };
```

Where my class is:

```
    class lineCommand {
    public:
        lineCommand(float startTime, float endTime);
        virtual ~lineCommand();
    //those are short inline functions:

    //setting the starting time of the command
    void setStartTime(const float num){mStartTime=num;};
    //setting the ending time of the command
    void setEndTime(const float num){mEndTime=num;};
    // returning the starting time of the command
    float getStartTime(){return mStartTime;};
    // returning the ending time of the command
    float getEndTime(){return mEndTime;};

private:
    float mStartTime;
    float mEndTime;
};
```

Not in the xgreater. I get error in eclipse saying:

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
float getEndTime()
```

Over the:

```
lx.getEndTime and rx.getEndTime
```

Comment: MCVE as usual here please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the function the following way

```
float getEndTime() const {return mEndTime;};
                   ^^^^^
```

In this operator declaration

```
    bool operator()( const lineCommand& lx, const lineCommand& rx ) const {
        return lx.getEndTime() < rx.getEndTime();
    }
```

parameters `lx` and `rx` are constant references. So you may call only member functions with qualifier const using these references.

The same way you could declare function `getStartTime`

```
float getStartTime() const {return mStartTime;};
```